# Excel add-in web app using SSO api 13004 error

Tags: office-js, officedev

I have developed an Excel add-in web app via ASP.NET web server using SSO like the following article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet

I have everything working locally, but when deployed to Azure, I get a 13004 error "Invalid application resource Url provided".  I have created an app registration like the article instructs, but I am unsure if I have all the parameters correct.  Locally, I have the following
Website is hosted at https://localhost:44355
Manifest resource is api://localhost:44355/[guid for app id]
Azure app id is api://localhost:44355/[guid for app id]

When deployed to Azure
My website is hosted at [websitename].azurewebsites.net
I tried many iterations of changing the Manifest resource and Azure app Id URI 
and all return the same error.

I tried leaving the original parameters with localhost:44355
I tried changing to my local domain (i.e. api:///[guid for app id])

Answer (score 1):

Can you compare the values in the App Manifest with what you have in your add-in manifest? You can go to you app in Azure portal, click on 'Manifest' and look at appID and identifierUris. Does this match what you have in your add-in manifest?